# EventSource in wordpress with python as backend

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, server-sent-events

I am working on building a webpage in WordPress using Server Sent Events(SSE) to show the live streaming data. Basically, trying to replicate the example from -

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

[WordPress Screenshot for Custom HTML block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zthHV.png)

**Front end** -  It's a "Custom HTML" block on the WordPress site, see the image.

**Back end**  -  There is a python script that continuously outputs data when executed from the server terminal.

**LiveData.py**
####################  File START ####################

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

printerLooper = True
secondsPause = 3

while printerLooper == True :
    print("Sleeping for ", secondsPause, " seconds")
    time.sleep(secondsPause)
    print("Current date and time : " , now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

####################  File END ####################

Few questions -

1 - How to specify the output of LiveData.py is of type 'text/event-stream' ?

2 - What should be the value of EventSource instance in the JS code ? Is it correct to specify the filename with absolute or relative path from where the HTML/JS is being called ?

3 - Should the LiveData.py publish the output to a webpage and then specify the webpage URL as the value of EventSource instance ?

I have watched a lot of videos on the YouTube and gone through GitHub repos as well, but there is always a code to build a server application (flask / redis) and then publish the output there which will be consumed by the front-end. In this case, there is already a WordPress application, so I really need to find a way to publish the output of LiveData.py so that it can be consumed by the WordPress page. Please share your views/feedback, will highly appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

The back-end script is working fine, meaning, there is a continuous stream of output data.

Expectation is to see the live output on a page of the WordPress site.